# How to use files names on command line copied in File Explorer?

Tags: command-line, powershell, windows-explorer

In Windows File Explorer, you can highlight several files and then click the "Copy path" button from the menu.  Show below is an example.  I'd then like to process these files on the command line, preferably in a PowerShell terminal.  I've tried enclosing them in more quotes, single quotes, and backticks, to no avail. Here's an example of the files copied to the clipboard:

"C:\Users\me\100_0909.jpg"
"C:\Users\me\100_0521.jpg"
"C:\Users\me\100_0519.jpg"

I'd like to be able to take the files above and include them in a command like:

magick "C:\Users\me\100_0909.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0521.jpg" "C:\Users\me\100_0519.jpg" +append new.jpg

Comment: The referenced thread did not answer the question, posting it again.

Comment: This is not copying file names, it is copying file objects for you to paste somewhere else. If you clicked like you said and hit copy, then tried to paste to notepad, you'll see this. To do what you are after it's, click one, copy the text from the Explorer path, paste into notepad, rinse and repeat for all files you are after. Basically creating a list, or just use Get-ChildItem directory of the files, send that to Out-GridView, select what you want, and with the -Passthru switch, pass that collection to whatever you want to process with. See the help files on Get-ChildItem and Out-GridView.